# Rails + Rspec: Where do I test app constants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I know unit tests go in `spec/models`, but where do constants defined in initializers and YAML files go?

Ex: This is in my ups_api.yml file:

```
testing_server:
  confirm_url: https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm
  accept_url: https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept
```

This is loaded in my config/environment.rb. Where/how would I test the value of these constants?

Answer (score 1):

I see no value in testing this sort of thing. You write tests to ensure the correct *behavior* of code. A configuration setting doesn't involved any kind of logic.